Oracle Apex Url parameter will deleted
My Oracle Apex url parameters will be overwritten by session id,
how can I prevent this behaviour?
Test ist working fine.
if I call the Apex App in Brower with 2 url parameters the session id will added to the address.
...home?reader_host_name=RBGR0174&reader_port=1
...home?reader_host_name=RBGR0174&reader_port=1&session=2988829469869
In my prod environment the url paramters will be "replaced" by the session id.
...home?reader_host_name=RBGR0174&reader_port=1
...home?session=753505822157
My App was exported from test and imported to prod (the app is equal)
test = version 23.1.4
prod = version 23.1.0

how the session is affecting your app, i don't get it

what is the purpose of those parameters and how are they used in the APEX app ? APEX builds it's own urls as you navigate through the app. The syntax of the url that is built by apex is documented here. If there are additional parameters I would expect those to be ignored.

I just add this two values in a text field and a select list field.
What is also strange,when I copy the two parameter after I got a session id, everything is working, as long the session id will be refreshed.
call the url => ...home?reader_host_name=RBGR0174&reader_port=1
automatically the session id will set and the params will be deleted...
home?session=753505822157
Then I copy ("&reader_host_name=RBGR0174&reader_port=1") after I got a session id, it works as long the sesson id was valid
...home?session=753505822157&reader_host_name=RBGR0174&reader_port=1

Please update the question with any relevant information, don't put it in an individual comment. Also, please take a step back and explain what it is you are trying to achieve, with as much detail as possible so anyone can try and reproduce. Describe the behaviour you are seeing and the behaviour you are expecting. I have no idea what you are trying to do based on the info you gave so far.

The problem was a setting in the Authentication Scheme.
It seems that the behaviour changed from version 23.1.0 to 23.1.4.
In Application/Shared Components/Authentication Schemes/
I set under Settings->Verify Username from "Each Request" to "After Login"
